# Showing data from database in Codeigniter

Tags: php, html, mysql, database, codeigniter

I have problems with showing data in Codeigniter, I have tried to code from an example but there is **An uncaught Exception was encountered**

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZqenP.png)

View :

```
<div class="row clearfix">
        <?php
        foreach ($devices as $de) {
            echo"
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="header bg-red" align="center" id="bID">
                        <h3 class="ketersediaan" id="ket">
                            Tersedia
                        </h3>
                    </div>
                    <div class="body" align="center">
                        $de->device
                        <br><br><br><br>
                        $de->capacity
                    </div>
                    <br>
                </div>
            </div>";
        }
            ?>
```

Model :

```
class Model_pelayan extends CI_Model
{

    function cekmeja(){
    $devices = $this->db->get('devices');
    return $devices;
}
```

It said that the Type of error is : Parse Error 
Message : Message: syntax error, unexpected 'col' (T_STRING), expecting ',' or ';'

Answer (score 2):

change

```
echo"
```

to

```
echo '
```

and close it with `';`

Since the inner html is using `"` so it breaks the string of php and gives you the syntax error.

Another good approach will be to close the php tag and just use

```
<?=$de->device?>
```

and other variables that you use to avoid syntax errors.

In your case it will be like this:

```
   foreach ($devices as $de) {
   ?>
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="header bg-red" align="center" id="bID">
                    <h3 class="ketersediaan" id="ket">
                        Tersedia
                    </h3>
                </div>
                <div class="body" align="center">
                    <?=$de->device?>
                    <br><br><br><br>
                     <?=$de->capacity?>
                </div>
                <br>
            </div>
        </div>

  <?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

As has been pointed out, you have a malformed string you are trying to `echo`. This is an alternate approach to solving the problem.

Often it is easier to drop in and out of the PHP processor than to try to write a long and complicated string for `echo`. With that in mind consider the following code.

```
<div class="row clearfix">
    <?php
    //drop into php processor for one line of code
    foreach($devices as $de) {
        ?>
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="header bg-red" align="center" id="bID">
                    <h3 class="ketersediaan" id="ket">
                        Tersedia
                    </h3>
                </div>
                <div class="body" align="center">
                    <?= $de->device; ?>
                    <br><br><br><br>
                    <?= $de->capacity; ?>
                </div>
                <br>
            </div>
        </div>
        <?php
        // back to php processor to close the foreach block
    }
```

It's easier to read and eliminates accidentally ruining the string with misplaced quote marks.

It is actually less processor intensive too because the HTML goes straight to the output buffer instead of PHP having to create a string from a text literal and then `echo` that string to the output buffer.

In case you are not familiar with this syntax

```
<?= $de->device; ?>
```

That is the same as writing

```
<?php echo $de->device; ?>
```

You might also want to consider using *PHP: Alternative Syntax for Control Structures*. Read about it [HERE](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php). The following is the same as shown earlier but using the alternative syntax.

```
<div class="row clearfix">
    <?php //drop into php processor for one line of code
    foreach($devices as $de) :
        ?>
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="header bg-red" align="center" id="bID">
                    <h3 class="ketersediaan" id="ket">
                        Tersedia
                    </h3>
                </div>
                <div class="body" align="center">
                    <?= $de->device; ?>
                    <br><br><br><br>
                    <?= $de->capacity; ?>
                </div>
                <br>
            </div>
        </div>
        <?php   // back to php processor to close the foreach block
    endforeach;
```